# emacs workspace/executeCommand with `vscode.java.resolveMainClass` failed

Tags: lsp, java, dap

I'm trying to debug java in emacs.I'm running the command `M-x dap-java-debug` in emacs and I'm getting below error.

> emacs workspace/executeCommand with `vscode.java.resolveMainClass` failed.
> (error "The connected server(s) does not support method workspace/executeCommand.
>
> To find out what capabilities support your server use `M-x lsp-describe-session` and expand the capabilities section")

Attached is the screenshot of the error.

My emacs configuration is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/emacs.d).

[image: dap-debug-java-error]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: The language server you're using doesn't support `workspace/executeCommand`

Comment: @nega lsp-java supports dap mode.

Comment: `lsp-java` isn't a language server.

Comment: Strip your config down to the bare minimum.  Make sure your language server is installed correctly. Try again. Do what the error message suggests.